# SQL Date Range Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, asp-classic, ado

I have a SQL2005 database with a table that has a field that is in datetime format and hold the date and time that a record was added. A typical entry looks like 10/03/2011 13:35:15

How do I query the table for records using a date range from ad asp page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `between` operator should be able to do the trick.

```
select 
    * 

from YourTable where DateField between '10/1/2011' and '10/5/2011 11:59:59 PM'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Adam, I've been trying the between operator and it wasn't working. What is the relevance of having the time on the end date (and not on the start date)?

Comment: Should make no difference. An omitted time string usually translates to 00:00:00

Comment: @Darren - By default it will start at the very beginning of the day 12:00:00 AM if you don't specify a time.  To make sure you get all of the second date/day, you want to append 11:59:59 PM so you get results that may come in at the last minute.

Comment: Sorry, try again. This is my code:sStartDate = "10/03/2011"
sEndDate = "11/03/2011 11:59:59 PM" 
sSQL = "Select * FROM MinutesUsedLog Where DateAdded Between '" & sStartDate & "' AND '" & sEndDate & "' ORDER BY DateAdded DESC". But this is not returning any regords?

Comment: @Darren: Have you tried running your command within SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all the rows in your table for a give Start Date (@StartDate) and End Date (@EndDate):

```
 select 
    *
 from 
    [TableName]
 where
    [DateToTest] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Just replace [TableName] and [DateToTest] with your values.